# Scrapy crawlspider rule not working for next pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl next page links using crawlspider but I am not able to get any result if I change parse function to something else. My Rule is not working.I am able to fetch only current page with parse function.Where am I going wrong.

This is my naukri_spider.py file

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from naukri.items import NaukriItem

class NaukriSpider(Spider):
    name = "naukri"
    allowed_domains = ["naukri.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.naukri.com/information-technology-jobs?xt=catsrch&qf[]=24"]

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]/a/button[@class="grayBtn"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),
)

    def parse(self,response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@class="content"]'):
            item = NaukriItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="desig"]/text()').extract()
            item['location'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="loc"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['organization'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="org"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: check the `warning`: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parse` method implemeted by `CrawlSpider` used to follow links. Change your rule callback to `parse_start_url` and override it.

This code works fine.

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from stackoverflow.items import NaukriItem

class NaukriSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "naukri"
    allowed_domains = ["naukri.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.naukri.com/information-technology-jobs?xt=catsrch&qf[]=24"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('information-technology-jobs.*', )), callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self,response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@class="content"]'):
            item = NaukriItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="desig"]/text()').extract()
            item['location'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="loc"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['organization'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="org"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```